# How can I get the number of iterations in AMPL?

Tags: iteration, ampl

I can get the number of variables using `_nvars`. Then, I tried `_niters` and `_niterations` but don't work.

I have also searched it in the manual unsuccessfully.

Is there a simple way to get the number of iterations, other than extracting it from `solve_message` (e.g. with regular expressions)?

Comment: It seems to me, it is only printed in the message but isn't accessible programatically in an AMPL script. You could try asking this question at the [AMPL mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/ampl), you may get a better answer directly from the developers.

Comment: However, the [time statistics are available](http://www.ampl.com/FAQ/#WheredoIfindtheamountofcomputation%28CPU%29timetakenbyAMPLorbyasolver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no built-in parameter representing a number of iterations in AMPL. In fact, this is very solver specific and different solvers and even different algorithms within a single solver may have multiple different iteration counts, such as MIP iterations, Simplex iterations, master iterations when using decomposition, etc. Your best bet is probably to parse the solver message.